# Unable to load class org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.MavenPomMetaInfoProvider

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-arctic-fox

I updated Android Studio to version Arctic Fox 2020.3.0.0 . Then I updated the gradle plugin to version `7.0.0` and the gradle in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file to `gradle-7.0.2-bin`. Now I have this error while syncing:

```
Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.MavenPomMetaInfoProvider'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
```

Answer (score 2):

I'v solve this by deleting one line in `build.gradle:`

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
```